# 'a bar' means 'prohibiting completely' or 'the possibility of prohibiting'?

Tags: legal-terms

*Failure to provide the information required under sub-section (1) of this section is **a bar** to a claim for compensation under this Act, unless the Board is satisfied that the -*

In the sentence above, I wonder whether the word 'a bar' means 'prohibiting someone **completely**' or 'the **possibility** of prohibiting someone'. (Frankly speaking, I'm not convinced that the usage of the verb 'prohibit' is correct but I just want to know whether it is sort of possibility or not.

Answer (score 1):

A bar means to prohibit. When used in a statute as this is there is no discretion for the prohibition to be waived (subject to whatever the board can be satisfied about).

Comment: Given the OP is a non-native English speaker, I think you could be clearer that the Board *does* have some discretion.

Comment: @MartinBonner They only have the discretion that is given to them by the rest of the clause that hasn't been provided. I have said this in the answer.

Comment: You did say that.  My point is that you said it in a slightly oblique way - which may be confusing to a non-native speaker.  (If this was all in German, I might well have missed the implication of your parenthetical).

Comment: @MartinBonner please make whatever edits you feel will assist